# POST API in spring boot not working if DNS is used instead of IP

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, spring-boot

I have a REST API developed in Spring Boot application.

Consider an API: POST "/users" and has a body.

If I call this API using the IP it works but does not work with DNS.

```
Eg:
  http://abc.io/users -> doesn't work,
  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/wellness/users - > works

My DNS maps to "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/wellness".
```

Note: GET API works fine with DNS also.

Let us know if I need to enable any property on Spring boot application. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

In case anyone is looking for this issue i will explain my case:

- I was having a similar issue while doing the tests on Postman.
- I started using postman for this tests while the dns was not set yet, worked fine with the IP.
- I did the dns set up. Postman didn't work with the dns but yes with the IP.
- I did a quick test using code and not Postman. Works with the dns.

So at the end, the issue was made by postman and not by the dns.

Hope this help someone like me in the future.

Thanks,